# Malformed timezone in JodaTime

Tags: java, datetime, date, jodatime

I have the following snippet that uses Joda time:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH z")
String dateTime = dateTimeFormatter.print(new DateTime())
println DateTime.parse(dateTime, dateTimeFormatter)
```

But it throws the IllegalArgumentException:

```
Invalid format: "16 EDT" is malformed at "EDT"
```

What do I miss?

EDIT: Works great for `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [DateTimeFormat javadoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html), time zone names ('z') cannot be parsed.

**EDIT:**
To parse a timezone, I'd look into using 'Z' and the actual time zone offset (eg. -0500 for Eastern). Also there's the `withOffsetParsed()` method in DateTimeFormatter you may want to look into -- eg. `dateTimeFormatter.withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime("16 -0500");`.

Comment: So how can I parse such a string?

Comment: by matching it to a list of known time zones

Comment: 'Z' matches the numeric timezone offset. I've updated my answer to include some more information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that EDT is not a valid *unique* time zone name. The parser is very strict in this regard. EDT can apply to the United States or Australia.